# Solving Multiple Equations For Repeated Times With Different Initial Conditions Matlab

Tags: matlab, equation, equations

I have the following set of values in an array.

```
a = [a(1) a(2) ... a(1907)] 
Gamma(1)= (u*f(1))+(r*a(1))
```

`u` and `r` are constant and `f(n)` changes during each step and its initial value is f(1) = zero.

`f(n)` next values will be generated from solving these equations.

`h(1) = x(1) + Gamma(1)` for which `x(1)=0` and in next steps is constant. (c)

```
Z(1)= constant(T) * h(1)    
f(2) = constant(G) * Z(1)
```

These steps will repeated 1907 times. Any idea what should I do at all?

Comment: Use a for loop and write it down. Where exactly do you expect and problems? Besides your description is incomplete because `t` is unused and `x` is never defined.

Comment: x(1)=0 and in next steps is constant(c)

Comment: I don't know how to enter initial conditions in for loop.
t is useless i will delete it now.

Comment: You're going to need to gain a bit more understanding for us to help you. Start here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html

Comment: Because od sanctions Mathwork is out of reach in Iran. :)
I'll figure something out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can input your initial conditions into a very simple for loop.

```
% a, u, r, T, G are assumed available. 
f = zeros(1908, 1);
Z = zeros(1907 ,1);
Gamma = zeros(1907, 1);
x = [0; c*ones(1906, 1)];

for ii = 1:1907
    Gamma(ii) = u*f(ii) + r*a(ii);
    h(ii) = x(ii) + Gamma(ii);
    Z(ii) = T*h(ii);
    f(ii+1) = G*Z(ii);
end
```